# POST variable omitted when sending out CURL request in PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

I am sending out a POST request using CURL in php with several POST fields as an array:

```
$post = array(
    'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$phSearchHeader$ddType' => 'x',
    'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$phSearchHeader$txtPostcodeStandard' => 'x'
);

$ch = curl_init('xxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
```

but the

> ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$phSearchHeader$txtPostcodeStandard

variable never gets sent/the script on the end doesnt receive it. When I delete two characters and make it 64 characters long (meaning its 68 chars long now):

> ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$phSearchHeader$txtPostcodeStanda

it works perfectly. So my guess is, something is omitting this variable in the process because its too long.

Problem is, I cant figure out what and where is doing this. My guess was it could be suhosin.post.max_varname_length, but suhosin isnt even installed on the server.

The problem persists whether I send the $post array as the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS value, or leave it as serialized url string.

Any ideas how to fix this? I tried googling php/curl/post variable/key length to no avail.

This is the verbose output of the request:

```
* About to connect() to xxx port 80 (#12)
*   Trying xxx...
* Connected to xxx (xxx) port 80 (#12)
> POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 382
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 382 out of 382 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 15:42:52 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Closing connection 12
```

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you have a 66 character string that is something else? E.g. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn`?